# Sonar - OutOfMemory Error on Analysis of project with new Rules

Tags: java, code-analysis

I'm trying to analyze my Java project with Sonar. I've specified the sources and the class directories in the sonar-properties file. The classes folder has several sub directories. Whenever I try running the entire project, I end up getting a `OutOfMemoryError`. However, if I narrow down the classes directory to one of the sub folders, the project gets analyzed successfully. I tried changing the `JVM Xmx` options to no avail. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

`Sonar` will build your project and run Test cases for analyze code based on your rules. So if your test cases and build required more memory you will have to provide that. There are several options. First one is increase Heap size which you already tried. And also you can clear the build space and rebuild the source. If you don't want to tun test cases you can skip test cases to save memory.

Comment: Can you please specify how to skip the test cases

Comment: If you are using `maven` build plug-in you can skip test by `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

Comment: Unfortunately its not a maven project, but thanx for the suggestion